# Access QList object in QML

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

I have a little problem accessing a QList objects since Javascript. I have a C ++ class that allows me to perform SQL queries since QML / JS. Everything works, I get my results in C ++.

My problem is that I'd returned to QML an QList object.
This is my function in C++ to return SQL result (Note is a simple object with different attributes) :

```
QList<Note> Storage::setQuery(QString query)
{
    QList<Note> noteItems;
    QSqlQuery qsqlQuery;
    bool ok = qsqlQuery.exec(query);
    if(!ok)
    {
        qDebug() << "Error setQuery" << m_sqlDatabase.lastError();
    }
    else
    {

        while (qsqlQuery.next()) {
            Note my_note;
            QString note = qsqlQuery.value("message").toString();
            my_note.setMessage(note);

            noteItems.append(my_note);
        }
   }

   return noteItems;
}
```

But when I call this function from JS I get this error: `Unknown method return type: QList<Note>`
The problem is the return type, QML JS doesn't know the type `QList<Object>`, why? What do I do wrong

Comment: Can I ask you why do you wrap a string in a `Note` object? Can't you simply return the naked strings?

Comment: Tthis is an example in my code Note the object consists of several attributes, such as Int, String etc @skypjack

Comment: @simon You should try my answer.

Comment: I try your solution tonight @Ansh Kumar

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use c++ `QList` as a model in Qml, I would recommend you to use the following procedure. I'm using my own example, you might change it according to your needs.

**Storage.h**

```
class Storage : public QObject {
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<Note> getList READ getList)

public:
    QQmlListProperty<Note> getList();
    void setQuery(QString query);
    QList<Note> noteItems;;
private:
    static void appendList(QQmlListProperty<Note> *property, Note *note);
    static Note* cardAt(QQmlListProperty<Note> *property, int index);
    static int listSize(QQmlListProperty<Note> *property);
    static void clearListPtr(QQmlListProperty<Note> *property);
};
```

**Storage.cpp**

```
void Field::appendList(QQmlListProperty<Card> *property, Note *note) {
    Q_UNUSED(property);
    Q_UNUSED(note);
}

Note* Field::cardAt(QQmlListProperty<Note> *property, int index) {
    return static_cast< QList<Note> *>(property->data)->at(index);
}

int Field::listSize(QQmlListProperty<Note> *property) {
    return static_cast< QList<Note> *>(property->data)->size();
}
void Field::clearListPtr(QQmlListProperty<Note> *property) {
    return static_cast< QList<Note> *>(property->data)->clear();
}

QQmlListProperty<Note> Field::getList() {
    return QQmlListProperty<Note>( this, &list[0], &appendList, &listSize, &cardAt,  &clearListPtr );
}

void Storage::setQuery(QString query)
{
    QList<Note> noteItems;
    QSqlQuery qsqlQuery;
    bool ok = qsqlQuery.exec(query);
    if(!ok)
    {
        qDebug() << "Error setQuery" << m_sqlDatabase.lastError();
    }
    else
    {

        while (qsqlQuery.next()) {
            Note my_note;
            QString note = qsqlQuery.value("message").toString();
            my_note.setMessage(note);

            noteItems.append(my_note);
        }
   }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qmlRegisterType<Note>();
}
```

The `QQmlListProperty` class allows applications to expose list-like properties to `QML`. To provide a list property, a C++ class must implement the operation callbacks, and then return an appropriate `QQmlListProperty` value from the property getter. List properties should have no setter. When extending `QML` with C++ code, a C++ class can be registered with the `QML` type system to enable the class to be used as a data type within `QML` code.

Comment: The OP wants to return a list from a method, he doesn't want to define a new property for his objects. This is an overkilling solution.

Comment: He wants to send `QList` of class from c++ to `qml`. I thought he doesn't know  the basics. That's why I put a complete solution.

Comment: A complete solution that is wrong within the space of the question.

Comment: I think I've stripped the answer enough. What do you think ?

Comment: The problem was not the response, it's well formed. Anyway, the question is how to return a list from a method called `setQuery`, why you are suggesting to define a new property with its getter and setter. That's not what have been asked.

Comment: In my knowledge, sequence types supported transparently in `QML` are `QList<int>` , `QList<qreal>`, `QList<bool>`, `QList<QString>`, `QList<QUrl>`. The `QML` engine provides automatic type conversion between `QVariantList` and JavaScript arrays, and between `QVariantMap` and JavaScript objects. But these doesn't support custom class object as its list content. For transferring a `QList<object>`, one has to define a new property with its getter and setter. Please correct me if I'm wrong .

Comment: I still don't see any reason for being down-voted @skypjack

Comment: Besides the 3 comments above used to explain it, I'd agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you register Note as a meta type? Probably that's what's missing:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE

In Qt 4 you'll also have to register `QList<Note>`, but not in Qt 5.

Oh, and Note should probably be a `Q_GADGET`, otherwise you cannot access its contents from QML either. Make sure you use Qt 5.5+. Otherwise, you'll need `QList<Note*>` and make those `Note` objects inherit from `QObject`.

Comment: no I do not have register Note as meta type, I try this evening @milianw